# Get the Site Display Name from the API

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, api-v1

Is there a way to get the Site Name, like StackOverflow or ServerFault, etc.? In my app I let the user enter a url with a api for a Site and I will be great If I can tell him something like: "You Are connected to SITE";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`display_name` is now returned as part of the [/stats method](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/help/method?method=stats).

Comment: The link is broken. Probably this happened due to a change in the domain used. Current documentation URL https://api.stackexchange.com/docs

Answer (score 1):

As of May 9, 2023, https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites returns a list of sites. The property having the site name is "name".

```
{
      "aliases": [
        "https://www.stackoverflow.com",
        "https://facebook.stackoverflow.com"
      ],
      "styling": {
        "tag_background_color": "#E0EAF1",
        "tag_foreground_color": "#3E6D8E",
        "link_color": "#0077CC"
      },
      "related_sites": [
        {
          "relation": "meta",
          "api_site_parameter": "meta.stackoverflow",
          "site_url": "https://meta.stackoverflow.com",
          "name": "Meta Stack Overflow"
        },
        {
          "relation": "chat",
          "site_url": "https://chat.stackoverflow.com/",
          "name": "Stack Overflow Chat"
        }
      ],
      "markdown_extensions": [
        "Prettify"
      ],
      "launch_date": 1221436800,
      "open_beta_date": 1217462400,
      "site_state": "normal",
      "high_resolution_icon_url": "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/apple-touch-icon@2.png",
      "favicon_url": "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico",
      "icon_url": "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/apple-touch-icon.png",
      "audience": "professional and enthusiast programmers",
      "site_url": "https://stackoverflow.com",
      "api_site_parameter": "stackoverflow",
      "logo_url": "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/logo.png",
      "name": "Stack Overflow",
      "site_type": "main_site"
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

"styling": {
"tag_background_color": "#E0EAF1",
"tag_foreground_color": "#3E6D8E",
"link_color": "#0077CC"
},
"related_sites": [
{
"relation": "meta",
"api_site_parameter": "meta.stackoverflow",
"site_url": "https://meta.stackoverflow.com",
"name": "Meta Stack Overflow"
},
{
"relation": "chat",
"site_url": "https://chat.stackoverflow.com/",
"name": "Stack Overflow Chat"
}
],
"markdown_extensions": [
"Prettify"
],
"launch_date": 1221436800,
"open_beta_date": 1217462400,
"site_state": "normal",
"high_resolution_icon_url": "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/apple-touch-icon@2.png",
"favicon_url"